# Translate 404 page in Magento

Tags: magento, csv, translate

I've translated a whole webshop for a customer. The only page I still need to translate is the '404 not found' page. But I can't find it anywhere on my server.

Does someone know where the 404 page is located.

I'm talking about .csv files here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get 404 page in magento

You have to create **404 page** with **url key** as ***no-route*** on magento backend.

You can create custom html contents/designs for 404 page on the editor itself.

Answer (score 1):

**For Magento 2:**

- The 404-page is located in Content > Pages, with title 404 Not Found.
- [Picture of Magento 2-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkePL.png)
- Within the Stores > Configuration > Web, you set which page to load when encountering a 404-error. The default is the "404 Not Found".
- [Picture of Magento 2-settings for selecting 404-page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTfED.png)

To translate, there are then two options, 1) Edit existing 404-page. 2) Create a new page and select it as the default 404-page in the Store configuration. In these settings, make sure to select the appropriate store scope.

**For Magento 1:**

Process is similar, "404 Not Found" page can be found in (menu) CMS > Pages. The settings to select which page that gets delivered as the 404-page is in (menu) System > Configuration > Web, and search for  "CMS No Route Page".